Cannot connect to vCentre / vSphere using pyVmomi from Python
I am trying to establish a simple connection to my vSphere instance (version 7.0.3.01400) using pyVmomi from Python (version 3.12.1) and different approaches – see below.
This issue seems related to obsolete SSL protocol (no certificate required here) and I cannot find anywhere recent sample on how to make this work.
Please note that I can connect to vSphere via REST API and credentials without issue.
Example 1:
context = None
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

s = SmartConnect(host=vCENTER_HOST, user=vCENTER_USERNAME, pwd=vCENTER_PASSWORD, port=int('443'),sslContext=context)
Disconnect(s)

from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import ssl

context = None
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

s = SmartConnect(host=vCENTER_HOST, user=vCENTER_USERNAME, pwd=vCENTER_PASSWORD, port=int('443'),sslContext=context)

# Error: s = SmartConnect(host=vCENTER_HOST, user=vCENTER_USERNAME, pwd=vCENTER_PASSWORD, port=int('443'),sslContext=context)
# (line 961, in SmartConnect)    supportedVersion = __FindSupportedVersion(protocol, host, port, path,

Example 2:
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import ssl

s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
s.Verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

s = SmartConnect(host=vCENTER_HOST, user=vCENTER_USERNAME, pwd=vCENTER_PASSWORD, sslContext=s)

# Error: DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS is deprecated

Any help or sample script would be very much appreciated
I have tried several sample scripts (e.g. https://vcloudnine.de/first-steps-with-python-and-pyvmomi-vsphere-sdk-for-python/) but they all failed as being few years old and not updated.

My mistake.... I used the full url (e.g. "https://myservername") for the host where it should only be  the server name or IP (e.g. "myservername"). Too much used to other API systems requiring the full URL.

My mistake.... I used the full url (e.g. "https://myservername") for the host where it should only be  the server name or IP (e.g. "myservername"). Too much used to other API systems requiring the full URL.
